# Opposite of 'downvoted to hell'

Tags: colloquialisms

What would I say as the opposite of downvoted to hell? So if I wanted to say, "Wow, that question on the Hot Questions list really got upvoted to *xxx*!", what word would I use in place of *xxx*?

'upvoted to hell' just sounds weird, with both positive and negative connotations. 'upvoted to heaven' sounds off, I can't place my hand on it exactly.

Comment: The sky?  The stratosphere?  The clouds?  Out of this world?

Comment: Upovted to sky? Upvoted to stratosphere? Upvoted to clouds? Upvote out of this world? They all sounds so awkward

Comment: Upvoted "to beat the band"? (0:

Comment: Building on Hellion's suggestions, one can also use any number of astronomical destinations: the Moon, the Sun, Jupiter, Saturn, Neptune, Pluto, Alpha Centauri, Orion, Sagittarius, Horsehead nebula, &c; or if one wishes to be more mathematical than astronomical, one could use "infinity"

Comment: I'd say, "upvoted like crazy." It is not the *opposite* wording, but it expresses opposite concept: significant activity in a given direction.

Answer (score 1):

The colloquial opposite of *hell* is surely *high heaven*. Unfortunately the full idiom normally associated with "high heaven" is "stink to high heaven," which Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) says dates to circa 1600:

> **stink to high heaven** Also **smell to high heaven**. Be of very poor quality; also, be suspect or in bad repute. For example, *This plan of yours stinks to high heaven*, or *His financial schemes smell to high heaven; I'm sure they're dishonest*. This expression alludes to something so rank that it can be smelled from a great distance. [c. 1600]

Still, if something can stink to high heaven, I don't see why it can't be upvoted to the same place; and it probably doesn't even need a handbasket to get there.

Comment: just for my own research, does Christine Ammer provide a context in which "Stink/Smell to High Heaven" was first given? Thanks.

Comment: @ButterflyandBones: No, she doesn't. I did find one early (and possibly related) instance involving the phrase "stink to God" in Thomas Bastard, _Chrestoleros Seuen bookes of epigrames written by T B._ (1598): "Is it a worthy thing to digge vp bones?/ To kisse, t'adore the reliques of dead men?/ Alas how foolish were those sily ones,/ Which in times past did nought but burie them?/ But they perhaps for stinke did then refraine:/ But you doe worse to make them stinke againe:/ Yet in the very stinking this is odd:/ They stank to men then, now they **stinke to God**:"

Answer (score 0):

One might say  “upvoted to all get-out”.   From [www.collinsdictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-get-out), *all get-out* is US slang “used in comparisons to intensify an adjective”; from [www.merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20get-out), *all get-out* is “the utmost conceivable degree — used in comparisons to suggest something superlative”.  [Wordsmith.org](http://wordsmith.org/board/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=205859) cites a couple of uses of *get-out* in such senses:

> We look as elegant and as beautiful as get out.  <sub><sup>— 1838, J. C. Neal *Charcoal Sketches*, 12</sup></sub>
>   We got to dig in like all git-out.  <sub><sup>— 1884, Mark Twain, *Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, xxxviii. 325</sup></sub>